# Fail installation of tensorflow over conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have just installed anaconda latest version X64 for windows with python 3.7.

trying to install tensorflow ends up with the next error message:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> bleach==3.0.2=py37_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37hdce8814_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h343c172_0
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Create an environment and try to install..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to python 3.6 instead

Comment: Yep, I used your recommendation to down grade anaconda to 3.6 and it worked! Thanks