# Related to installing of tensorflow in python 3.7

Tags: tensorflow

As I am using the command prompt to run python when installing tensorflow it is saying requirment satisfied but when importing giving an error

```
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
     19         except ImportError:

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py in find_module(name, path)
    295     else:
--> 296         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    297 

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
     21             return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper

c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\chirag\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.   
Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Python 3.7 Doesn't support tensorflow yet, you will need to install python 3.6

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566365/importerror-importing-tensorflow/54566418?noredirect=1#comment95932805_54566418, the question is framed differently there but same solution applies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail installation of tensorflow over conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969443/fail-installation-of-tensorflow-over-conda)

Answer (score 0):

The [TensorFlow build from source on Windows guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) mentions it only supports Python 3.5 and Python 3.6.

Last time I installed tensorflow on Windows, if I recall correctly I used [Python 3.6.4 64-bit](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-364/). (I had some errors with Python 3.6.5 but that was last summer so there's a chance slightly newer versions of 3.6 might work).
Docs mention:

> Requires Python 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6

Because I wanted to install `tensorflow-gpu` I also had to be mindful of the CUDA Toolkit and CuDNN versions too (some combinations didn't work).
Unfortunately I don't remember the CUDA/CuDNN versions 100% but [documentation mentions CUDA 9.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) (e.g. Download cuDNN v7.0.5 (Dec 5, 2017), for CUDA 9.0

Looking at the nVidia [CUDA Archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive) that's from Sept. 2017 so I would go with a CuDNN version compatible with CUDA 9.0 from around that time from their [CuDNN Archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)(e.g. [7.0.5 for Windows 10](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7)).

Not 100% guaranteed if this will work, but something like this:

1. Uninstall Python 3.7 (unless you can find a simple way to install multiple version of Python and switch as needed, but doing quick searches reveal it's a bit of a headache on Windows)
2. Install Python 3.6.4 64 bit
3. Install pip (if it's not already installed) (download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run it)
4. Install [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)(`pip install virtualenv`, `virtualenv tf-gpu`,`.\tf-gpu\Scripts\activate`) (the point of the virtual environment is to keep a local tensorflow setup as opposed to a global module which might cause headaches with other projects using different TensorFlow dependency versions (`numpy`,`protobuf`,`six`,etc.)
5. Install [CUDA 9.0](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#installcuda-windows)
6. Install [CuDNN](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows) (7.0.5 or wee bit higher, but for CUDA 9.0 for sure)
7. Reboot, double check Windows Environment Variables for CUDA/CUDNN paths and verify the installs
8. Finally install TensorFlow with GPU support in the virtual environment:`pip install tensorflow-gpu` (will take a bit of time: might as well hydrate, etc.)
9. Hopefully the installation completed successfully in which case verify it: quick test: `python -c 'import tensorflow;print("TensorFlow version:",tensorflow.__version__)'`...if this doesn't throw errors and prints the version open run the [HelloWorld example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/1_Introduction/helloworld.py) (which should also print some CUDA info) once the session runs.

If you don't want `tensorflow-gpu` or don't have a tensorflow compatible GPU you can skip the CUDA/CuDNN part. I still recommend making a virtual environment (e.g. `tf-cpu`) then use `pip install tensorflow` instead of `pip install tensorflow-gpu` within the activated virtual environment.